# need to design timeout activity for android application

Tags: android, authentication, timeout

I need to design a timeout activity for my android application
These are my concerns-

- From every activity in the app the timeout would be 90 mins.
- On any activity in the app the timer should reset itself.
- there would be a authentication screen thereafter and it would return to the last activity
  upon success

What I need is a generic design as I may have parent-child relationship and would apply on events like onUserInteraction(),onPause() onStop() but it may result in lot of redundant coding and lot of methods to be taken care of.
Can I use services or any cross-cutting features like aspects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Implement one abstract class that extends your intended super class (i.e., `Activity`).
- Implement your "timeout" concept in that abstract class's `onUserInteraction()`, `onPause()`, `onStop()` methods.
- Extend that abstract class in your actual "worker" classes.

Comment: Thankss!!!.... 
just 1 thing more..even in general use these methods would be called numerous times on each action... is there any way to restrict calling?...because in 90 mins timeout period... it would affect performance..

Comment: 1. No,  I don't think you can't stop those methods; especially, onStop(). 2. You will be calling super class's methods anyway.